# messages log file flooded every minute

Tags: linux, logs

My `/var/log/messages` file gets flooded every minute with the following messages:

```
Dec 15 13:55:01 www systemd: Started Session 31 of user root.
Dec 15 13:55:01 www systemd: Starting Session 31 of user root.
Dec 15 13:55:01 www systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Dec 15 13:55:01 www systemd: Stopping User Slice of root.
```

What do these messages mean? Is there a problem with the server? Is there a way to stop them from flooding the log?

Comment: Does it correlate with a root-owned cron job?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, I have a cron job configured to run every minute. I have changed the schedule of that job and now the messages appear less often, at the same time the cron job runs. I guess it's normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively common on systemd based machines.  Events like this may happen when users login, cron jobs run, at jobs...

If you are running `rsyslogd` then it's possible to create a filter that drops these messages.

e.g. on RedHat (CentOS, etc), it's documented: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1564823

```
echo 'if $programname == "systemd" and ($msg contains "Starting Session" or $msg contains "Started Session" or $msg contains "Created slice" or $msg contains "Starting user-" or $msg contains "Starting User Slice of" or $msg contains "Removed session" or $msg contains "Removed slice User Slice of" or $msg contains "Stopping User Slice of") then stop' >/etc/rsyslog.d/ignore-systemd-session-slice.conf

systemctl restart rsyslog
```

This will prevent local logging of these events:

```
"Starting Session"
"Started Session"
"Created slice"
"Starting user-"
"Starting User Slice of"
"Removed session"
"Removed slice User Slice of"
"Stopping User Slice of"
```

You can adjust the filter to your needs.

Comment: Very good to know! In my case it was a cron job that was running every minute, I have changed its schedule. Now these messages are logged less often in `/var/log/messages`.